# How do I add options to a built in function, which only apply to a certain class of argument?

Tags: options, coding-style, upvalues

I'd like to add an option to a built-in function that only applies when it is given an argument of a certain form.

For example, something like this approach to extending `DateString` to support an extra option when it is given a date argument that matches the form `zoned[...]` (forget that `zoned` does nothing here):

```
DateString[zoned[x_], spec_, opts : OptionsPattern[{TimeZone -> 0,ShowZone->True}]] ^:= 
DateString[x, If[OptionValue[ShowZone],
   Append[spec, If[OptionValue[TimeZone] != 0, "UTC" <> ToString[OptionValue[TimeZone]], "Z"]], spec]]
```

Since `ShowZone` is not an option for `DateString`, I get an error.

> "DateString::optx: Unknown option ShowZone in DateString..."

But I can't just associate `TimeZone` as an up value for `zoned` with

```
zoned/:Options[DateString]={ShowZone->True}
```

because that also results in an error:

> Options::tag: Rule for Options of Options[DateString] can only be
>   attached to DateString.

It seems I have to (unprotect `DateString` and) then add a new option globally, which is generally just ignored:

```
Unprotect[DateString]; 
Options[DateString] = Union[Options[DateString], {ShowZone -> False}]; 
Protect[DateString];
```

Is this the only approach? Even this approach leaves `ShowZone` blue in the function definition and red in function invocations.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you add some sample use which leads to an error?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: "Options::tag: Rule for Options of Options[DateString] can only be attached to DateString."

Comment: I dont see why do you need that definition at all (the one with `Options`). The following input, for example, works without a problem: `DateString[zoned[{1959, 8, 29, 0, 0, 0}], {"Year"}, ShowZone -> True]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: (Sorry, the error above is for the assignment as an upvalue.) The error I get from using `ShowZone` in `DateString` is: "DateString::optx: Unknown option ShowZone in ..."

Comment: Then we are back to my original request: please add an example illustrating the error. Generally, it is a good practice to provide fully self-contained description, not to  make us guess the missing parts.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Edited.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I can run your definition (`DateString`) with no problems, and no errors reported. I am on Win7 64 bit, and tested on both M8 and M9.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: I can't reproduce it in a clean kernel either. I'll have to look through the execution and see what happens in the context where I get this error. I've made no assignments involving `DateString`, `zoned`, or `ShowZone` up to that point, so I'm puzzled; but I'll see what I can uncover.